# Login/Signup API implementation in iOS Shopify

Tags: ios, api, authentication, shopify

I am developing an Mobile app using shopify SDK, however I am not able to find anything to implement Login/Signup into my app. I have done shopping cart/products but unable to implement customer login. Is there any solution to implement login/signup using Shopify in app or any bridge I can create between shopify and custom PHP services.

Thanks.

Comment: hello dude.. you make app. using Shopify API ? in iPhone ?

Comment: HI,Sorry for inconvenience. I hope you may finished a project using Shopify. I need your help can you please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910777/shopify-sync-cart-with-customer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shopify's [customer](https://docs.shopify.com/api/customer/?ref=microapps) object from the API.

Comment: There is no option to get Password, for sign-in we required Password. From this API there is no such option.

Comment: Sir, I am Working on recoverPassword API, getting some error plz help me.
My Code is,==>  
[self.client recoverPasswordForCustomer:txtEmail.text callback:^(BUYStatus status, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error){
            NSLog(@"NO ERROR");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Failed to create customer: %@", error.userInfo);
        }
    }];
I am getting this error,
Error Domain=BUYShopifyErrorDomain Code=404 "(null)"

Failed to create customer: {
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shopify API which is given in tutorial, I have give code for Login and Sign up.

**Code for Login**

```
 NSArray *credentialItems = @[
                             [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithEmail:self.txtEmailID.text],
                             [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithPassword:self.txtPassword.text],
                             ];
 BUYAccountCredentials *credentials = [BUYAccountCredentials credentialsWithItems:credentialItems];

[self.aClient loginCustomerWithCredentials:credentials callback:^(BUYCustomer * _Nullable customer, BUYCustomerToken * _Nullable token, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (customer && token && !error) {

        NSLog(@"Login Done");

    } else {
        //NSLog(@"Failed to login customer: %@", error.userInfo);
        _lblMessage.text=error.localizedDescription;
    }
}];
```

**Code for Sign Up**

```
NSArray *credentialItems = @[
                             [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithFirstName:self.txtFirstName.text],
                             [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithLastName:self.txtLastName.text],
                             [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithEmail:self.txtEmailID.text],
                             [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithPassword:self.txtPassword.text]
                             ];
BUYAccountCredentials *credentials = [BUYAccountCredentials credentialsWithItems:credentialItems];

[client createCustomerWithCredentials:credentials callback:^(BUYCustomer * _Nullable customer, BUYCustomerToken * _Nullable token, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (customer && token && !error) {

        self.txtFirstName.text =@"";
        self.txtLastName.text = @"";
        self.txtEmailID.text=@"";
        self.txtPassword.text=@"";

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Shopify" message:@"Signup successfully" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:okAction];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Shopify" message:error.localizedDescription preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alertController addAction:okAction];
        [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

        //NSLog(@"Failed to create customer: %@", error.userInfo);
    }

    }];
```

Comment: HI,Sorry for inconvenience. I hope you may finished a project using Shopify. I need your help can you please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910777/shopify-sync-cart-with-customer

Comment: hi how can I implement facebook login in shopify ?