# i am implementing shopify mobile sdk iOS, and while creating a new customer i am getting error "nil URL argument"

Tags: objective-c, shopify

This is my code:

```
NSArray *credentialItems = @[    
                             [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithEmail:self.textFieldCustomerEmail.text],
                             [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithPassword:self.textFieldPassword.text],
                             [BUYAccountCredentialItem itemWithFirstName:self.textFieldCustomerName.text]
                             ];
BUYAccountCredentials *credentials = [BUYAccountCredentials credentialsWithItems:credentialItems];
 BUYClient *user = [[BUYClient alloc] initWithShopDomain:@"##############" apiKey:@"#############" appId:@"#########"];       
[user createCustomerWithCredentials:credentials callback:^(BUYCustomer *customer, BUYCustomerToken *token, NSError *error){
        }];
```

And this is error:

> shopify[10128:196747] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSBundle initWithURL:]:
>   nil URL argument'

Comment: Which line is causing the issue exactly?

Comment: BUYClient *user = [[BUYClient alloc] initWithShopDomain:@"##############" apiKey:@"#############" appId:@"#########"];                                                                                on on debugging it is not creating user.                                                  "user BUYClient * nil 0x00000000"

Comment: i got solution for that.....

Comment: i was giving wrong appId....

Comment: HI,Sorry for inconvenience. I hope you may finished a project using Shopify. I need your help can you please look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910777/shopify-sync-cart-with-customer

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can find the answer, if you don't then please visit here...

[Login/Signup API implementation in iOS Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651027/login-signup-api-implementation-in-ios-shopify/39527793#39527793)

You have to declare BUYClient in AppDelegate and assign Shop_Domain, Api_Key and App-Id in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.